# Parameters.Add in sql project c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm making a login and signup form and when i'm trying to sign up it's putting the user and password in the sql database but it's doing this :
 [image]
my project looks like this :

```
        static public void Insert(string _userName)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCeCommand commandInsert = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Table](username) VALUES(@userName)", connection); 
            commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@userName", _userName);
            commandInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlCeException expection)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(expection.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }



    static public void Insertt(string _password)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCeCommand commandInsert = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Table](password) VALUES(@Password)", connection); ;



            commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@password", _password);

            commandInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlCeException expection)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(expection.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

and the button sign up looks like this :

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (insertBox.Text != "" || deleteBox.Text != "")
                {
                    SQLFunctions.Insert(insertBox.Text);
                    SQLFunctions.Insertt(deleteBox.Text);
                    SQLFunctions.Refresh(this.dataGridView1);

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("login failed");
                }
            }
```

thanks for any help

Comment: please describe the problem, don't just throw us a program and expect us to debug/fix it for you

Comment: Why are you inserting the username and password on separate records?  Why have two functions for this at all?  What makes `Insertt` different from `Insert`?  Also, please don't store user passwords in plain text.  If users are trusting you with their passwords, properly hash those passwords so they can't be read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inserting *two* records:

```
SQLFunctions.Insert(insertBox.Text);
SQLFunctions.Insertt(deleteBox.Text);
```

Each of those functions inserts a record into the table.  So it shouldn't be at all surprising that you end up with two records.  I imagine it would make more sense to just insert *one* record:

```
SQLFunctions.Insert(insertBox.Text, deleteBox.Text);
```

And in the function:

```
static public void Insert(string _userName, string _password)
{
    // ...
    SqlCeCommand commandInsert = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Table](username, password) VALUES(@userName, @password)", connection); 
    commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@userName", _userName);
    commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@password", _password);
    // ...
}
```

Each value doesn't need its own separate database query, entire records can be inserted/updated in a single query.

---

A few other notes...

- *Thank you* for using parameterized queries.  You'd be amazed how many people don't :)
- You're storing user passwords in plain text.  Please ***never do this***.  User passwords should be hashed and should not be readable after they've been stored.  (Ideally they should be hashed *right away* when received by your code and you should only ever use the hash value for anything, that way they don't accidentally end up in a log dump either.)
- You might want to consider more meaningful/correct names for variables/functions/etc. It will drastically help your debugging efforts, especially as you create more complex things.  For example, `Insert` and `Insertt` don't really tell you what they're doing, or what's different about them.  Also, why does `insertBox` have a username and `deleteBox` have a password?  That's just misleading.  Don't underestimate the importance of good naming.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two mistakes here that can lead to your problem.

First - in your `button1_Click` event you have :

`if (insertBox.Text != "" || deleteBox.Text != "")`

which causes the first problem - having empty columns in your database. Instead check like this:

`if (insertBox.Text != "" && deleteBox.Text != "")`

In fact even better use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to check this so:

`if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(insertBox.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(deleteBox.Text))`

Second, you don't need and must not use two queries for inserting this. So make it one query with two parameters :

```
SqlCeCommand commandInsert = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Table](username, password) VALUES(@username, @password)", connection);

commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@username", _username);
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@password", _password);
```